# How to change log level in F# Saturn Framework?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, f#, saturn-framework

When I run my Saturn app, I see some logs being written to the console.

Looks like they start with the `LogLevel.Info`. How do I engage more detailed logging, i.e. how to properly set e.g. `LogLevel.Trace`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to go is setting `logging` in the Saturn [app builder](https://saturnframework.org/docs/api/application/#application-builder):

```fs
let app = application {
    pipe_through endpointPipe

    router topRouter
    url "http://0.0.0.0:8085/"
    memory_cache
    use_static "static"
    use_gzip
    logging configureLogging
}
```

And you can do configuration like this:

```fs
let configureLogging (logging: ILoggingBuilder) =
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace) |> ignore
```

The only Saturn example I found is [here](https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn/blob/341c231ff8812a761acb87854551eded440ae6fb/sample/CsrfSample/CsrfSample.fs#L40), in the Saturn samples. There are [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#default-minimum-level) for ASP.NET Core, on top of which Saturn is built.

The default log level is [indeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#default-minimum-level) `LogLevel.Info`:

> If you don't explicitly set the minimum level, the default value is Information, which means that Trace and Debug logs are ignored.

[Remember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel) not to set `LogLevel.Trace` for production:

> These messages may contain sensitive application data. These messages
>   are disabled by default and should never be enabled in a production
>   environment.

Comment: You will need  *open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging*